# gRCP - Unable to Call Server Method

Tags: java, c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

So I have a C# gRCP Server running on Visual Studio with a Remote Method that takes in a String and just responds to the client "Hi"+{String} back nothing too fancy.
I'm almost 100 sure there is nothing wrong with the Server because I'm using the template provided by VS and I can hit the server using a External Tool,

I'm trying to create a JAVA Client to Hit that same server, But keep running into this error
*UNIMPLEMENTED: Service is unimplemented*

And on my C# Server Console it says

*info: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.ServerCallHandlerFactory[1]
Service 'Greeter' is unimplemented.*

**JAVA Client Side**

```
import com.mycompany.grpc2.GreeterGrpc;
import com.mycompany.grpc2.Greet;
import io.grpc.*;

public class GrpcClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("running..");
        String name = "Billy";

        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 5014).usePlaintext().build();
        GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub stub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

        Greet.HelloRequest req = Greet.HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(name).build();
        Greet.HelloReply reply = stub.sayHello(req);

        String x = reply.getMessage().toString();
        System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

**Here is also the .Proto File**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.mycompany.grpc2";

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
  rpc ByTwo (NumRequest) returns (NumReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}

message NumRequest{
  int32 num = 1;
}

message NumReply{
  int32 numByTwo = 1;
}
```

**C# Server Side**

```
using Grpc.Core;
using gRPC_Server;

namespace gRPC_Server.Services
{
    public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        //Hello Service
        public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + request.Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
// Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
// For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682

// Add services to the container.


builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();



// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");



app.Run();
```

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "gRPC_Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5014;https://localhost:7014",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be Greatly appreciated,
Thanks for reading

Comment: Can you show us the C# end?  My first guess is a problem there.

Comment: Hi Louis, of course I can, Ill edit the origian post (:

Comment: Could you add the java code as text and not as photo and could you share the C# code where you register the service to the Server instance ? I'm guessing you just forgot to register the service.

Comment: @ClémentJean Hey Clement I appreciate the help, Ye no problem (: I added it just there, I didnt do that, Is that what's missing you think ?

Comment: Could you share your `launchSettings.json` too? it is under the `Properties` folder. And also mention on which OS you are please.

Comment: @ClémentJean ofcourse buddy

Answer (score 0):

## Old answer - before having the `Program.cs`

You probably missed registering the service in you server, you should instantiate your gRPC Server in the following way:

```cs
Server server = new Server
{
    Services = { Greeter.BindService(new GreeterService()) },
    //...
};
```

If you do not do that, the client will always get a `Status.UNIMPLEMENTED` because the server doesn't have a registered definition of your gRPC endpoint.

## New answer

It seems you are registering the `GreeterService` with the `app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>()` and it also seems that you are working with the new gRPC framework (gRPC .NET not C-Core).

So I tried copying all the code and setting that you have, I created a C# server and a Java Client and I just couldn't get the same error. I never tried that hard to make a program not work. Here are my suggestions:

- Make sure that you are not running an older version of your server (one that didn't implement the `SayHello`)
- Make sure to use the same proto file for both project. Do not copy/retype the content since that could lead to typos and thus to communication errors
- Clean the generated files (build/generated for Java and obj/{Debug or Release}/net6.0/ for C#), you can do that by going in `build` and then `clean project`. Then you can rerun the generation.

Comment: Aw really, Thanks man, So Does the Java Client work for you, do you get the Server response ?  And if so, For you're Java Client would you mind sharing you're pom.xml file (:

Comment: The client works properly for me yeah. I'm using Gradle on the server side though. For getting a working pom.xml (which I think is not your issue), you can check on the  [grpc-java GitHub examples dir](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples).

Comment: Thanks Clement, Gradle yeah, I never worked with Gradle but I'll give it a go it might work better with gRPC , would you mind sending us you're Java Client Project (:

Comment: @ShaneH using Gradle is pretty simple. You can follow the README in [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java). Only reading the Download and the Generated code section should be ok. Just be careful to use Gradle for non android. And finally on top of your dependency block add `sourceSets.main.java.srcDir new File(buildDir, 'generated/source')` which adds the generated code to your code path so that you can use it inside your java package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried numerous solutions.

Finally I have solved it by making my java client proto file read as below. The critical line was ensuring I had the same package line as in my server .proto file (in my case package greet;)

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "GrpcGreeter";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
  rpc AddNums (HelloRequest2) returns (HelloReply2);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}


message HelloRequest2 {
  int32 a = 2;
  int32 b = 3;
}

message HelloReply2 {
  string message2 = 4;
}
`

Regards
Ben
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33175097)

Comment: I have managed to fix my problem. It was the .proto file. I removed the option csharp_namespace in the java client .proto file because it wasn't C#. But I also commented out the package line, which was package greet. Once I put that line back in and regenerated the stubs I could get it to work. Shane H has only supplied the prot file for the java client and it doesn;t have a package line. Maybe there is one in the C# server proto file and therefore if you add it to the java client proto file it may solve your problem like it did for me.

Comment: I modified my answer and I believe it does answer the question now.